# can .webpart be converted to .dwp?

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to convert any .webpart file to a .dwp so that I would

1. Export a .webpart file
2. Convert it to .dwp file (add every property in dwp format)
3. Import it back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.dwp` web part file corresponds to [SharePoint-based web parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.aspx) and `.webpart` to  [ASP.NET web parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.aspx), web part file can not be converted without rebuilding web parts itself.

### The difference between [SharePoint-based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.aspx) and [ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.aspx) web parts

> The set of features provided exclusively by
>   [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.aspx) is as follows:
>
> - Cross page connections
> - Connections between Web Parts that are outside of a zone
> - Client-side connections (Web Part Page Services Component)
> - Data caching infrastructure, including the ability to cache to the    database

### Example: convert Content Editor web part file format (V2 -> V3)

An attempt to convert SharePoint-based web part file from version 2 (MSContentEditror.dwp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
    <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
    <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>
    <Title>Content Editor</Title>
    <Description>Allows authors to enter rich text content.</Description>
    <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
</WebPart>
```

to version 3 (MSContentEditror.webpart):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c,Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title">Content Editor</property>
        <property name="Description">Allows authors to enter rich text content.</property>
        <property name="PartImageLarge">/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

will give an error during adding web part on page.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more... I think it is possible to create a web part and then use both .dwp and .webpart files to import it on page (dont remember if this applies to both SP based and ASP.NET based web parts).

Comment: The answer has been updated to reflect why it does not seem possible just to convert file format

Comment: Ok, I think this is fine. I also haven't gotten this to work with out-of-the-box web parts (although I think I've used both for self-created web parts some time ago).